# Imagemagick: convert TIF image to EPS keeping resolution

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, eps

I have been trying to convert an tif image to an eps image keeping the original resolution for days. But without success. The problem is that imagemagick always sets the resolution of the eps image to 72 dpi regardless of using the density and resize command before or after the input file.

[The input file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10895659/input.zip.html) can be downloaded, for example I tried following imagemagick command (all of them without the desirable result):

```
convert -density 300 input.TIF -profile "ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc" eps3:output.EPS
convert -density 300 input.TIF -profile "ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc"  -geometry 2835x3780 eps3:output.eps
convert -density 300  input.TIF -profile "ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc" -resize 2835x3780 eps3:output.eps
```

What is wrong on my conversion? I just need an output eps image with the the resolution of 300 dpi as the input tif file.
Added: identify of output.eps

```
Image: output.eps
  Format: PAM (Common 2-dimensional bitmap format)
  Mime type: image/x-portable-pixmap
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 680x907+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 9.44444x12.5972
  Units: Undefined
  Type: ColorSeparation
  Base type: ColorSeparation
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: CMYK
  Depth: 16/8-bit
  Channel depth:
    cyan: 8-bit
    magenta: 8-bit
    yellow: 8-bit
    black: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 616760
    Cyan:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 8034.92 (0.122605)
      standard deviation: 16075.5 (0.245296)
      kurtosis: 3.34548
      skewness: 2.18869
    Magenta:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 63993 (0.976471)
      mean: 6431.6 (0.0981399)
      standard deviation: 13251.7 (0.202209)
      kurtosis: 4.41467
      skewness: 2.36107
    Yellow:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 62965 (0.960784)
      mean: 3296.53 (0.0503018)
      standard deviation: 8665.27 (0.132224)
      kurtosis: 11.9555
      skewness: 3.37656
    Black:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 61166 (0.933333)
      mean: 3413.91 (0.052093)
      standard deviation: 10294.1 (0.157078)
      kurtosis: 10.6052
      skewness: 3.33169
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 5294.24 (0.0807849)
      standard deviation: 12400.4 (0.189219)
      kurtosis: 7.42941
      skewness: 2.89771
  Total ink density: 324.706%
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: cmyk(255,255,255,0)
  Border color: cmyk(223,223,223,0)
  Matte color: cmyk(189,189,189,0)
  Transparent color: cmyk(0,0,0,0)
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 680x907+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-09-09T10:21:04+02:00
    date:modify: 2015-09-09T10:21:04+02:00
    ps:HiResBoundingBox: 680.4x907.2+0+0
    ps:Level: Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0

    signature: 141246e610fe99f6d715095d32098b493a3258c58c755dd44cacb68b5be4129a
  Artifacts:
    filename: output.eps
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 2.467MB
  Number pixels: 617K
  Pixels per second: 9.223372EB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x64 2014-08-26 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Added: identify of temp.png

```
Image: temp.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2835x3780+0+0
  Resolution: 300x300
  Print size: 9.45x12.6
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 16-bit
    green: 16-bit
    blue: 16-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 10716300
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 56707.6 (0.865302)
      standard deviation: 17939.1 (0.273732)
      kurtosis: 3.27011
      skewness: -2.18726
    Green:
      min: 771 (0.0117647)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 57871 (0.883055)
      standard deviation: 16384.1 (0.250006)
      kurtosis: 3.99522
      skewness: -2.33806
    Blue:
      min: 1419 (0.0216526)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 60137.5 (0.91764)
      standard deviation: 13808.7 (0.210707)
      kurtosis: 6.52445
      skewness: -2.76051
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 58238.7 (0.888665)
      standard deviation: 16134.1 (0.246191)
      kurtosis: 4.60442
      skewness: -2.44957
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.45455
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 2835x3780+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-09-09T10:16:17+02:00
    date:modify: 2015-09-09T10:18:20+02:00
    png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)
    png:cHRM: chunk was found (see Chromaticity, above)
    png:gAMA: gamma=0.45454544 (See Gamma, above)
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 16
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 16
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
    png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 2835, 3780
    png:pHYs: x_res=300, y_res=300, units=0
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    png:text: 4 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
    ps:HiResBoundingBox: 680.4x907.2+0+0
    ps:Level: Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0

    signature: dffc47b2e7b1b0bdc1c8afe849bc84561743fe757c4ebb5093487547f67f2d9d
  Artifacts:
    filename: temp.png
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 13.38MB
  Number pixels: 10.72M
  Pixels per second: 20.61MB
  User time: 0.530u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.520
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x64 2014-08-26 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and operating system?

Comment: I think the output of `identify` may be misleading you - EPS files are vector files and you generally specify the resolution when you read them in. Try running `convert -density 300 output.eps temp.png` and look at the dimensions and quality of the `PNG` file.

Comment: I use the following version:  
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x64 2014-08-26; Features: DPC Modules OpenMP; Delegates: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: @Mark: I've run your command, and attached the "identify"-files to my question above.  
Do you mean, that the identify information of the converted eps file is wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run the `convert` command I suggested? Do you get the original image back in its original size and quality?

Comment: Yes, the png file has the same size and resolution as the original tif file (done conversions: tif -> eps; eps -> png).